# MySQL Workbench and Optional Many's

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have used workbench before to make databases code wise and I just started looking into its EERD functions. I created a small database for a test project and found some odd things about how MySQL workbench did things. I am trying to make sure this program is working correctly before I use it for larger projects.

I created an EERD that looks like this:

```
(User)||---o<(Permissions)>o---||(Rooms)||---o<(Posts)||---o<(Target)
```

I forward engineered it to my database and it went through fine, everything seems to look ok (don't have data to test it with). I then reverse engineered that database and it switched all of the optional manys into mandatory(1) manys.

Is this a cosmetic issue with workbench or can I not forward engineer optional manys?

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Comment: No and it's been so long I forget what happened. Might as well close this.